# Integration test with Cucumber + Guard + Spork: Can I access my REST entry point?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, integration-testing, spork, guard

I can manually test my API via *rails s* and point my HTTP client to http://127.0.0.1:3000/api.

Now, I want to automatically test my API via features. So I successfully set up a guard server which starts cucumber and rspec.

Does cucumber start my application and provide my API entry point under any port? So that I can use a HTTP client inside my step definitions and point it to http://127.0.0.1:8989/api for example?

I know that I can specify a :cucumber_port => 4321 in the Guardfile but my API is not available under this port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Cucumber doesn't start your application with server.

To test it you can do the following:

1. Use rack_test. It provides you with methods like `#get`, `#post`, etc. It's preferred. For example:

```rb
get('api/test')
response.code.should == '200'
```

1. Start you server with Capybara. It'll be much longer however. You can do this by adding the following code to `env.rb`:

```rb
require 'capybara/rails'
Capybara::Server.new(Capybara.app).boot
```

Now you can access your API at `http://127.0.0.1:9887/api`

Comment: OK this line was the solution Capybara::Server.new(Capybara.app).boot . I don't use Rack::Test but I can now reach my API in my step definitions. Additionally I can fix the port with Capybara.server_port = 9887